# Tensorflow linear classifier not training

Tags: python, tensorflow, linear-regression, mnist

I'm trying to create a simple linear classifier for MNIST data and I can not get my loss to go down. What could be the problem?
Here is my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data

class LinearClassifier(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print("LinearClassifier loading MNIST")
        self._mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("mnist_data/", one_hot = True)
        self._buildGraph()

    def _buildGraph(self):
        self._tf_TrainX = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, self._mnist.train.images.shape[1]])    
        self._tf_TrainY = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, self._mnist.train.labels.shape[1]]) 

        self._tf_Weights = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([784,10]), tf.float32)
        self._tf_Bias = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]), tf.float32)
        self._tf_Y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(self._tf_TrainX, self._tf_Weights) + self._tf_Bias)

        self._tf_Loss = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(self._tf_TrainY * tf.log(self._tf_Y), reduction_indices=[1]))
        self._tf_TrainStep = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001).minimize(self._tf_Loss)

        self._tf_CorrectGuess = tf.equal(tf.argmax(self._tf_Y, 1), tf.arg_max(self._tf_TrainY, 1))
        self._tf_Accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(self._tf_CorrectGuess, tf.float32))

        self._tf_Initializers = tf.global_variables_initializer()

    def train(self, epochs, batch_size):
        self._sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True))
        self._sess.run(self._tf_Initializers)

        for i in range(epochs):
            batchX, batchY = self._mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size)
            self._loss, _, self._accurracy = self._sess.run([self._tf_Loss, self._tf_TrainStep, self._tf_Accuracy], feed_dict ={self._tf_TrainX: batchX, self._tf_TrainY: batchY})
            print("Epoch: {0}, Loss: {1}, Accuracy: {2}".format(i, self._loss, self._accurracy))
```

When I run this via:

```
lc = LinearClassifier()
lc.train(1000, 100)
```

... I gett something like this:

```
Epoch: 969, Loss: 8.19491195678711, Accuracy: 0.17999999225139618
Epoch: 970, Loss: 9.09421157836914, Accuracy: 0.1899999976158142
....
Epoch: 998, Loss: 7.865959167480469, Accuracy: 0.17000000178813934
Epoch: 999, Loss: 9.281349182128906, Accuracy: 0.10999999940395355
```

What could be the reason why the tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer is not training my weights and bias correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main thing is your learning rate (0.001) is too low. I ran this after changing it to 0.5 like they did in the [mnist tensorflow tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/mnist/beginners) and I'm getting accuracy and loss more like:

```
Epoch: 997, Loss: 0.6437355875968933, Accuracy: 0.8999999761581421
Epoch: 998, Loss: 0.6129786968231201, Accuracy: 0.8899999856948853
Epoch: 999, Loss: 0.6442205905914307, Accuracy: 0.8999999761581421
```

Another thing that's a little unusual is in your original code you have this

```
self._tf_Y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(self._tf_TrainX, self._tf_Weights) + self._tf_Bias)
self._tf_Loss = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(self._tf_TrainY * tf.log(self._tf_Y), reduction_indices=[1]))
```

In this case you would be doing the softmax twice. I did run it before changing that and the train accuracy was around 85% so it does make some difference. Also doing the softmax twice is less theoretically interpretable.

Finally, they mention in the tutorial that using the form of the softmax above, `-reduce_sum(label * log(y))`, is numerically unstable, so it's better to use the builtin softmax layer which calculates an analytically equivalent but more numerically stable softmax. After applying these two changes, the affected lines look like:

```
self._tf_Y = tf.matmul(self._tf_TrainX, self._tf_Weights) + self._tf_Bias
self._tf_Loss = tf.reduce_mean(
  tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=self._tf_TrainY, logits=self._tf_Y))
```